# how to host WCF Duplex service on internet

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, duplex

i have a WCF service with WSDualHttpBinding, the service works fine locally, when i host it on the IIS it does not work,first it was asking for credentials to login where no authentication was setted up on the binding, however i set he security mode to none now when i make a request from the client it just waits waits and waits for the response and times out.

any suggestion or an example will be appreciated.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name ="NewEngine.Engine" behaviorConfiguration ="serviceBehaviourSoap" >
        <endpoint name ="duplexendpoint" address ="" binding ="wsDualHttpBinding" contract ="NewEngine.IEngine" bindingConfiguration="wsDualBinding"/>
        <endpoint name ="MetaDataTcpEndpoint" address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehaviourSoap">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsDualHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsDualBinding" closeTimeout="00:00:05" openTimeout="00:00:05" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:05" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
          <security mode="None" >
            <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: "locally" and IIS seem to be two different things to you, have you tried hosting it on your PC *in IIS* to find the problems?

Comment: Posting your configuration will help.

Comment: @nvoigt yes it works on our development server IIS, but as soon as i deploy it outside our corporate network i face the problem

Comment: @christiandev i have updated the question with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem last week. i deleted this line < message clientCredentialType="None" /> its worked well. you can try it